# Alternative to Iteration for INSERT SELECT UPDATE in a sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, query-string

I have a table with around 17k unique rows for which I need to run these set of statements in sequence

- INSERT INTO TABLE1 using MASTERTABLE data (MASTERTABLE have 6 column)
- SELECT value of column ID (Primary Key) of newly inserted row from TABLE1
- Update that ID value in TABLE2 using a Stored Procedure

I have tried:

- while loop: took around 3 hours to complete the execution
- cursor: cancelled the query after executing it overnight
- In my understanding I can not use JOIN as I need to execute the statements in a sequence

Comment: I assume ID is identity.  The question needs a lot more detail.   Look up output. VTC as not clear but I will remove that when you provide more detail.

Comment: @paparazzo kindly have a look at the updated question

Comment: Still lacking enough detail for me.  I give up.

Comment: The answer can be found here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: have you considered an `INSERT TRIGGER` on `TABLE1` from wich to call stored procedure on `TABLE2`?

Comment: if it is just to update the ID in table2, why do you need the SP, is there some kind of special logic done in that SP, or can you do the update without using the SP. The `OUTPUT` clause is your friend (in the insert statement) to get the list of IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questions is not detailed enough. The general idea I would like to use something like this

```
-- create a output table to hold new id, and key columns to join later
DECLARE @OutputTbl TABLE (ID INT, key_Columns in MASTERTABLE)

INSERT INTO TABLE1
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID, MASTERTABLE.key_columns INTO @OutputTbl 
SELECT *
FROM MASTERTABLE 

UPDATE T2
SET ID = o.ID
FROM TABLE2 t2
INNER JOIN OutputTbl o
  ON t2.key_column = o.key_column
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider a `TRIGGER` on `TABLE1` from which to call the stored procedure on `TABLE2`, and then you can call your `INSERT` as you wish/need.. one by one or in blocks..

```
DROP TRIGGER TR_UPD_TABLE2 
GO

CREATE TRIGGER TR_UPD_TABLE2 ON TABLE1 AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @columnID INT = NULL 

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED)=1 BEGIN
        -- SINGLE INSERT
        SET @columnID = (SELECT columnID FROM INSERTED)

        EXEC TableTwoUpdateProcedure @columnID

    END ELSE BEGIN
        -- MASSIVE INSERT (IF NEEDED)
        SET @columnID = 0

        WHILE @columnID IS NOT NULL  BEGIN
            SET @columnID = (SELECT MIN(columnID) FROM INSERTED WHERE columnID > @columnID)

            IF @columnID IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                EXEC TableTwoUpdateProcedure @columnID
            END
        END

    END 
END
```